# Rails 3 - Validating Multiple Instances of a Model Against Each Other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, architecture, refactoring

I'm working on an app that handles employee timecards, and I'm trying to create a form that allows employees to edit all of their punches in a given block of time. I used [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/198-edit-multiple-individually) as the foundation for the form, and was able to get things up and running with no trouble:

```
class BlocksController < ApplicationController

def update
    @block = Block.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @punches = @block.punches

    keys = params[:punches].keys
    values = keys.map { |k| params[:punches][k] }
    @punches = Punch.update(keys, values).reject { |p| p.errors.empty? }
    if @punches.empty?
      flash[:notice] = "Punches updated"
      redirect_to employee_timecard_path(current_user, @block.timecard)
    else
      render :action => "edit"
    end
  end
```

The problem, though, is that I need to be able to validate that the user didn't edit their punches in a way that doesn't make sense (e.g. changing their clock-in punch to be later than the clock-out punch, or vice versa).

I tried doing this through a custom model validation, but the individual models passing through the validation have no knowledge of the other values being updated, so the first punch in the batch is comparing its new value against the pre-update values of the others.

The only other approach I could think of was to loop through the `params[:punches]` being sent to the update method in the controller, but this seems to run contrary to the convention of "fat model, skinny controller".

Is there any way I can have my cake and eat it too? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: I still think you're kind of stuck looping through the punches in Block controller.  Controllers should be allowed to grow fat if it's appropriate. In your case I think it is.  The only things I could think of that would reduce controller code were inefficient,  calling the ActiveModel layer unnecessarily just to keep the controller thin didn't seem like a good tradeoff,  kind of like smoking cigarettes to stay thin!

Comment: Could you use an after or around filter? The worst you could do is save everything to the database, check it in an after filter, and then have to undo it somehow. I don't understand around filters that well, but from what I gather that might give you a way to check the updates as a group before they are saved, and abort the save if your validations fail. See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters

Comment: As far as where the validations go, I suppose you could set up a class method for Punches that validates the entire set (or some scoped subset) of records (maybe returning a list of id's for records that fail, for example).

Comment: @SteveRowley That's basically what I've done for now. I took the code I wrote in the controller and pasted it into a method within the model, passing the params hash along with it. It's still a pretty ugly solution, I think, but at least it works.

Comment: For what it's worth, if I was new to the code and looking for methods that validate sets of some object, I'd look in the code for the class, not the code of a controller for another class, so to be honest that sounds ok to me, but I can see why someone else might think it's less than ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with a similar problem:

1. Schedules have a start and end date
2. Schedules shouldn't overlap with each other

Here's what I've concluded:

There are two kinds of validity going on here:

1. The validity of the individual models (e.g. does a start date exist?)
2. The validity of the collection of models (e.g. do any pairs of instances overlap?)

I feel like only the first type is actually the responsibility of the individual models. But the second type isn't the responsibility of the controller either.

In the OP's case I'm not sure if it would be best to define a validator on the Punch class, or to create a new object with responsibility for validating the whole list of punches, but one way or another there should be some object which knows about the whole collection and can decide whether it's valid or not.